# ID of matrix printed instead of value

Tags: craft2

I have strange issue and cannot find out the solution for that.
I have this field (matrix with some text values): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgWM7.jpg

Also I have this entry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALAuL.jpg

And this is how it rendered (it shows not value of fields but id of matrix block table): https://i.stack.imgur.com/twsHX.jpg

Here is how it looks like in template: https://pastebin.com/viVbPLqj

I've tried multiple combinations but nothing was solution. Also other fields are works well (fields which not related to "companyInformation" matrix).

So what may I do wrong?

Comment: When you dump `reviewFeatured.relatedCaseStudy.first.companyInformation.companyName` what is the result ?

Comment: @MaximeLafrenière it's here (marked by red cycle): https://imgur.com/a/SR3HgQZ
It's an ID of companyInformation in 'matrixblocks' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the data you're seeking are under the first matrix block (not the first data of your `.companyName` - which is not valid)

```
{% set relatedCaseStudy = reviewFeatured.relatedCaseStudy.first %}
{% set firstCompany = relatedCaseStudy.companyInformation.first %}
{{ firstCompany.companyName }}
```

Note: If you plan to have only one company, think about a [SuperTable](https://github.com/verbb/super-table) field in 'static' mode (only one occurence).

Comment: And how to find out what field types I need to fetch via "first", and which not? I've installed "inspector" plugin but it ain't helps. Twig's dump function also not good (absolutely exactly).

Comment: `.first` is in fact a function that return the "first" element of an array/object. Every 'simple' fields (text, dropdown, etc.) aren't concern by this method. 

You can read the whole documentation fields that on Craft' website. There's a example for each field.

(https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/fields.html#field-types)